# In Windows, Mac, Linux is there a centralised facility for tracking changes/deletion/new files?

Tags: windows, linux, file-management, notifications

Is there are feature in Windows (and other OSs such as MacOS and Linux) that when you use Open... in your favourite image editor to view files, it provides an option: recent additions - whereby you can open files recently copied or moved from a pen drive etc or those produced as output from another program.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be useful if ..." is not really a question. Also, why is this tagged "linux" if your question is about Windows?

Comment: Updated the question body, the tagging and title already spoke of both. Also added Apple/Mac - since I run all of them: Apple MacOS, Windows XP, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.0x at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems that, at the moment, there isn't such a facility or add-on to provide what I was looking for. The traffic count for this question, visits, suggest that not many others require this feature (perhaps at the moment?) and therefore the necessity (being the mother of invention) is not strong enough to develop such a service.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a rheotorical question.

Programs can use ReadDirectoryChangesW in windows to watch for file events (add, delete, change) and do whatever is wanted with that information.

Whether you *should* do such things is however a separate matter.

Comment: Thanks. My question is about convenience, whereby there is a centralised service that provides a list of recent files added or modified, of the type that an Open File dialog in an application would be interested in, e.g. images, audio etc. Currently, one has to "hunt" i.e. navigate through folder hierarchies to find what was new. "Recent Documents" only works for files that have already been opened and it's not available as an option in am Open File(s) pop-up dialog.

Comment: You can certainly get the Linux kernel to inform you of changes in this fashion (e.g. inotify) and write a program that maintains such a list and, if you like, you can even patch the GTK file picker to provide that list. If that's something you're interested in I recommend that you do it and submit/publish the patches. In Windows I imagine something similar can be done, except that patching the file picker is harder.

Comment: Windows XP had the Recently used documents feature ("Documents" on the start menu) which seems to be what you describe. I never used it because it drove me crazy.

Comment: as I said  "Recent Documents" only works for files that have already been opened, AFAIK

Comment: +1 for your comment @phogg about how this might be implemented for various platforms.